# What is the normal colo(u)r of a selected stringgrid row?

Tags: delphi, winapi, tstringgrid

I am overriding `OnDrawCell` for a string grid. In certain circumstance, I want to use the normal `TColor` that is used for the selected row when the system does the drawing (no `OnDrawCell`).

Which colo(u)r is that? clXXX ?

Comment: It's `clHighlight`... see `Grids.pas`, method `TCustomGrid.Paint`, inner procedure `DrawCells` (in Delphi 2009).

Comment: @TLama Pelase post that as an answer and I will award. Thanks

Comment: @TLama The color depends of the [DrawingStyle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.DrawingStyle) property of the TStringGrid,  for gdsClassic  use clHighlight, for gdsGradient use StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clHighlight) ,for gdsThemed  with vcl styles StyleServices.GetStyleColor(scGrid) and so on ....

Comment: @RRUZ, d'oh, you're right, I forgot that Emba made the string grid cool that way (I have just that boring, non themed SG in my Delphi 2009 :-) And this question is for XE2 I guess. Taking back my comment...

Comment: @RRUZ, TLama: Any answer that will be given will be along the lines of what you two just wrote in your comments, so just post it as an answer that can be up-voted and accepted.

Comment: @RRUZ, TLama but your both probably forgotten VCL Skins ? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before of Delphi 2010 you can use the `clHighlight` color.

In Delphi 2010 the TStringGrid, TDrawGrid and TDBGrid components now have a [`DrawingStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.DrawingStyle) property and depending of this value (gdsClassic, gdsGradient, gdsThemed) you must calculate the color on this way.

1.for **gdsClassic**  use `clHighlight`;

2.for **gdsGradient** use the [`GradientFillCanvas`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.GraphUtil.GradientFillCanvas) method

```
GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, GetShadowColor(clHighlight, 45), GetShadowColor(clHighlight, 10), LRect, gdVertical);
```

3.for **gdsThemed**   call the `DrawElement` method of the `TCustomStyleServices`

```
StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tgCellSelected), LRect, ARect);
```

In Delphi XE2 (and XE3) with the introduction of the vcl styles you must use the same of the above but checking if the current style is a "custom style" (vcl style)

1.for **gdsGradient** use the GradientFillCanvas method calculating the colors of the gradient on this way

```
StyleServices.GetElementColor(StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tgGradientCellRowSelectedRight), ecGradientColor1, StartColor); //StartColor is a TColor variable
StyleServices.GetElementColor(StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tgGradientCellRowSelectedRight), ecGradientColor2, EndColor);//EndColor is a TColor variable
```

2.for **gdsClassic**

```
StyleServices.GetElementColor(StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tgClassicCellRowSelectedRight), ecFillColor, LColor); //LColor is a TColor variable
```

If you want check a sample of how the VCL draw a selected (highlighted) cell/row try the implementation of the `TCustomGrid.DrawCellHighlight` method.